# Import fontawesome into laravel mdbvue environment

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, import

I tried to add `fontawesome` to my laravel `mdbvue` environment

When I install `mdbvue`

```
npm install mdbvue
```

`fontawesome` will automatically be added to my `package-lock.json` and exists in the node_modules folder in `@fortawesome`.

Now I want to implement fontawesome. **But how?**

I tried something without success:

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
```

**Info:** When I add

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
```

to my html-header it works.

---

**Edit:**
There seems to be a difference between using xampp and php artisan serve. When I use the last one, all icons are displayed correctly.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this article](https://mdbootstrap.com/articles/vue/mdb-vue-laravel-quick-start-guide/) importing fontawesome in resources/js/app.js file should work.